# Seam conversation ending suddenly when using Redirect

Tags: java, jsf, redirect, seam, seam-conversation

Because I get some errors on conversations ending abruptly, I created in my project some test pages that reproduce the issue. The navigation takes place between pageA.xhtml and pageB.xhtml. Please tell me if I am using something in the wrong way.

My configuration:
Seam 2.2.0.GA
WebLogic 10.3.2 (11g)
Richfaces 3.3.2
JSF 1.2

Note: the same happens when using annotations to begin / end conversations

=======

## PAGE A

```
@Name("pageaAction")
public class PageaAction {

        @Out(required = false, scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
        Person person;

        public String rule3() {

                person = new Person();
                person.setEmail("someone@gmail.com");
                person.setName("markos");
                return "rule3";
        }
}





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page>
        <navigation>
                <rule if-outcome="rule3">
                        <begin-conversation />
                        <redirect view-id="/pages/seam_sandbox/pageb.xhtml" />
                </rule>
        </navigation>
</page>

...
<h:commandButton action="#{pageaAction.rule3()}" value="h:commandButton" /><br/>
...
```

=======

## PAGE B

```
@Name("pagebAction")
public class PagebAction {

        @In(required = false, scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
        Person person;

        public String redirectA() {

                return "redirectA";
        }

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page>
        <navigation>
                <rule if-outcome="redirectA">
                        <end-conversation before-redirect="true" />
                        <redirect view-id="/pages/seam_sandbox/pagea.xhtml" />
                </rule>
        </navigation>
</page>

...
<h:commandButton action="#{pagebAction.redirectA()}" value="h:commandButton" />
...
```

==========

## EXCEPTION:

This happens after a random number of redirects.

> javax.faces.FacesException:
>
> ## {pagebAction.redirectA()}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>
> conversation context active
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
>           at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:324)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:299)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:256)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:469)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:530)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
>           at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
>           at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>           at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
>           at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>           at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
>           at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>           at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
>           at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>           at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
>           at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
>           at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>           at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
>           at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>           at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3592)
>           at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>           at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2202)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2108)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1432)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
>   Caused by:
>   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   conversation context active
>           at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>           ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   conversation context active
>           at org.jboss.seam.ScopeType.getContext(ScopeType.java:133)
>           at org.jboss.seam.Component.getValueToInject(Component.java:2325)
>           at org.jboss.seam.Component.injectAttributes(Component.java:1736)
>           at org.jboss.seam.Component.inject(Component.java:1554)
>           at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:61)
>           at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>           at org.jboss.seam.core.ConversationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(ConversationInterceptor.java:65)
>           at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>           at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
>           at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>           at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
>           at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
>           at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
>           at eu.emea.pim.prs.web.seamsandbox.PagebAction_$$_javassist_seam_8.redirectA(PagebAction_$$_javassist_seam_8.java)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
>           at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:280)
>           at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
>           at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.invoke(AstMethodSuffix.java:65)
>           at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
>           at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
>           at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
>           at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>           ... 46 more

Comment: Thanks for the response once again! This IS a redirect-after-post scenario. Why is it rare? You use redirect if you want your address bar to show the page you are seeing. When in page A, user clicks, makes POST request to A, which redirects him to page B. So, page B is both in the screen and in the address bar. After that, user clicks in page B, makes POST request to B, which redirects him to page A. So now page A is both in the screen and the address bar. What is incorrect?

Comment: ok, you are using Seam 2.2 and Weblogic App server. Before going on, Try to test by using JBoss App server and see what happens. If something goes wrong, tell me and i will try by myself by using a similar scenario. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the name of the seam EJB module. By default it is named the way Maven has the jar named:

> jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar

whereas Weblogic only works with

> jboss-seam.jar

Created an issue in the JBoss Jira, contains an easy workaround.

https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBSEAM-4644

Comment: Good job, Markos (+1) It could cause a lot of headache To non-Web-logic users, such as myself