# Problem install seam on weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, weblogic, seam

I guys,

I need to install jboss-seam on weblogic server.
I read the [seam documentation](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.2.0.GA/fr-FR/html_single/#weblogic) but after many problem, I have another problem which I can't resolve.

When I deploy my ear on weblogic, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet
```

However, I installed jsf as the doc describes and I don't understand this error. How to resolve it ?

Thanks for your help.

PS: I use weblogic 10.3 and jboss-seam 2.2.0 with workshop for weblogic 10.3.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453746/jboss-seam-enabling-debug-page-on-weblogic-10-3-2-11g and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713364/seam-conversation-ending-suddenly-when-using-redirect It can be useful

Comment: Are you getting NoClassDefFound errors as well?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with Seam on WebLogic 10.3.2 (11g), which was caused by the name of the seam jar file. The name was jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar and the installation only worked after I renamed it to jboss-seam.jar.

It doesn't seem to be related to your issue, but you could give it a shot.

The Jira issue I created is this:

https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-4644